# Represent Null values as blank in xml with java

Tags: java, xml, excel, dom

My Excel data values are:
Name    EmployeeId  Address Phone
Rony    FBL123  Dhaka   12333333
Azam    FBL321  Dhaka   67778888
Rony        Chandpur    099776655
Azam            9988

---

Here is my code to read a list of data values including null values:
And convert data into xml:

```
try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = build.newDocument();

    Element root = doc.createElement("dataroot");
    doc.appendChild(root);

    Element Details = doc.createElement("DATA");
    root.appendChild(Details);


    for(int i=0; i<list.size()-2; i +=3 ) {

        Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
        name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(list.get(i))));
        Details.appendChild(name);

        Element id = doc.createElement("Empid");
        id.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(list.get(i+1))));
        Details.appendChild(id);


        Element ad = doc.createElement("Add");
        ad.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(list.get(i+2))));
        Details.appendChild(ad);


        Element mo = doc.createElement("Mobile");
        mo.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(list.get(i+3))));
        Details.appendChild(mo);


    }
```

Here where i need to check the data is null or not and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be doing this where you add the element in your `list` using `add()`. This part of code snippet is however NOT on your post above. 
Assuming `list` is defined as `ArrayList<String>` and `val` is of `String` type, you can do something like:

```
if (val == null) {
   list.add("");
}
else {
   list.add(val);
}
```